# Bulk/Mass Edit Video Audio?

Tags: video, audio, video-editor

I have 100 videos that need editing so that I can level the and amplify the audio track. However I do not want to have to extract the mp3 track from each one and edit it then merge it again with the video. this is aloooonggg process.

Is there a software that can achieve this or something similar?

Comment: Slightly relevant: http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/5615/batch-video-editing-software-that-can-trim-without-re-encoding

Answer (score 2):

you can use `avconv` (the ffmpeg utility replacement) and `mp3gain` to script extracting, adjusting and merging the files.

The advantage using mp3gain is that it does not reencode the audio but just adjust levels. So you don't lose any quality. It has a nice automatic mode that work descent although not perfect.

Answer (score 1):

This is a given for any professional video editing package.  Audio effects should be able to be applied to the video tracks to make the necessary adjustments.  The exact details depend on your software of choice.